# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

using react code (full class source is shown at the end of this article question), receive TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current') on the code line (in the render function)

```
<ul>
     {Component.messageHistory.current.map((message, idx) => (
            <span key={idx}>
                 {JSON.stringify(message.data, null, 4)}
            </span>
     ))}
</ul>
```

and message history is defined as a constant so in principle render function should be able to get to its properties (messageHistory uses hook so it has to be defined in a function)

```
const messageHistory =  useRef([])
```

```
import React, { Component, useCallback, useMemo, useRef  } from "react";
import useWebSocket, { ReadyState } from 'react-use-websocket';
import Select from "react-select"
import "./index.scss";

export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    Component = () => {
        const socketUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_URL;

        const { sendJsonMessage, lastJsonMessage, readyState } = useWebSocket(
            socketUrl,
        );

        const messageHistory =  useRef([])

        messageHistory.current = useMemo(
            () => messageHistory.current.concat(lastJsonMessage ?? []),
            [lastJsonMessage],
        );

        const handleClickSendMessage = useCallback(() =>
                sendJsonMessage({
                    event: 'subscribe',
                    subscription: 'test.test',
                }),
            [sendJsonMessage],
        );

        const handleClickUnSendMessage = useCallback(() =>
                sendJsonMessage({
                    event: 'unsubscribe',
                    subscription: 'test.test',
                }),
            [sendJsonMessage],
        );

        const connectionStatus = {
            [ReadyState.CONNECTING]: 'Connecting',
            [ReadyState.OPEN]: 'Open',
            [ReadyState.CLOSING]: 'Closing',
            [ReadyState.CLOSED]: 'Closed',
            [ReadyState.UNINSTANTIATED]: 'Uninstantiated',
        }[readyState];

    };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="signals">
                        <button
                            onClick={Component.handleClickSendMessage}
                            disabled={Component.readyState !== ReadyState.OPEN}
                        >
                            Subscribe
                        </button>
                        <button
                            onClick={Component.handleClickUnSendMessage}
                            disabled={Component.readyState !== ReadyState.OPEN}
                        >
                            Unsubscribe
                        </button>
                        <span>The WebSocket is currently {Component.connectionStatus}</span>
                        {Component.lastJsonMessage ? (
                            <span>
                    Last message:{' '}
                                {JSON.stringify(Component.lastJsonMessage.data, null, 4)}
                            </span>
                        ) : null}
                        <ul>
                            {Component.messageHistory.current.map((message, idx) => (
                                <span key={idx}>
                        {JSON.stringify(message.data, null, 4)}
                    </span>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Function components are effectively instanceless, all the `Component.X` accesses should just be `X`. You don't call functions defined in a React component via the component itself. You should also not declare React components inside other React components. This is all some very weird code.

Comment: I agree @DrewReese on weirdness and I dont want it to be , essentially if I dont use qualifier Component (as in just messageHistory.current.map((message, idx) =>) I get ReferenceError: messageHistory is not defined

Hooks need to be declared in a function, useRef([]) is such a hook , and its current holds Map to values which I want to render 

how do I declare this hook in a class (because if I just use function App() that works all just fine, but in a class I need some function to declare that hook

thanks much for your time

Comment: Well, React hooks are only valid in function components and custom hooks, they are not compatible with class components. You can either convert `Home` to a function component and use the hooks, or *not* do just about everything the current code is doing. Let's take a step back and ask what is the use case here, what is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: general use case is , websocket connection is established , json payload arrives and populates a map which then is dumped to a display 

technically

1. being able to use class defined component such as example export default class Home extends Component  and not function App() component

2. have hook defined in some kind of function (to persist that map) (example has Component = () => ) and have render function "get to it" and display it

Comment: could be not possible! cause Component.messageHistory render function is capable of accessing but Component.messageHistory.current not, but messageHistory is a constant so wouldnt all its properties of it also be accessible ? all code works in there except this, its more of a mystery really , problem is simple

Comment: I'm guessing it's more to do with `Component` not being rendered as a React component so none of the React component lifecycle and hooks are really being instantiated and maintained. You are basically abusing React function component syntax so the linter is warning you about invalid hook usage, and then because the component isn't being rendered by React you aren't getting the runtime invalid hook usage errors.

Comment: Generally you would establish the socket connection and listener when the component mounts (`componentDidMount` or `useEffect` with empty dependency array), and unsubsscribe when it unmounts (`componentWillUnmount` or a cleanup function returned from the mounting `useEffect`), updating *some* local component state with transmitted data.

Comment: there are coders using class components and functions (last example in that link , none though accesses .current hook property directly but just hook itself and that works

`
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const RenderCounter = () => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // Every time the component has been re-rendered,
    // the counter is incremented
    counter.current = counter.current + 1;
  }); 
  return (
    <h1>{`The component has been re-rendered ${counter} times`}</h1>
  );
}; 
`
https://medium.com/trabe/react-useref-hook-b6c9d39e2022

Comment: its also for me to know a limit or even improper or abuse of syntax so very much appreciate the feedback, I will go the route of componentDidMount or useEffect as advised , want to stick to pure react syntax as much as possible, thank you!